# Ubuntu freezes, then page slowly becomes consumed by static

Tags: 14.04

I couldn't find a similar description to this problem so I hope I'm not repeating a previously asked question.

We recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 on a computer that is also running Windows XP. The installation ent fine, and Ubuntu boots up fine, but after 2 or 3 minutes, it freezes, and then the page slowly becomes consumed by black lines and static (it's almost like a defrag screen from the olden days). I've tried the REISUB solution at this point and it's not allowing us to do that either.

Being as I'm very new to Ubuntu, and only having limited time to use the OS before it crashes, can anyone advise what to do to diagnose / resolve this problem? We're wondering if it's Kernel related...

Many thanks in advance.